# Fixing Script Error Invalid Pointer from ArcGIS Geoprocessing Tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase

I am just learning ArcGIS 10.2 and it was working well until I tried to use the Export to a Geodatabase (single) option for a dbs table I made. Since then, it seems I now get the same Script Error for import/export functions. However, I just tried to export to Geodatabase (multiple) and error did not pop up.
I spoke with tech support and they could not help me so far. I really do not know much about GIS so it is hard for me to fix this problem and cannot proceed with some things.

Comment: Are you doing this through the GUI or by script.  Is the exact script error "script error invalid pointer"?

Comment: There should be more to it than that... are you using 64bit background processing? That can give funny errors like this, perhaps turn it off (more about it here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Foreground_and_background_processing/00210000003q000000/). It is also possible that the error is 'in the past' so consider clearing your geoprocessing history (more here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131405/how-to-remove-geoprocessing-history-in-arcgis-10-2-2-for-desktop)

Comment: I have done it through ArcMap and ArcCatalog. Both ways it does it. That is the actual message. Title is Script Error, then says Line 63 then Char 4 then Error: Invalid Pointer then next line says Code 0

Answer (score 9):

I just solved this problem.
What you need to do is the following:
In Windows go to: Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program.

Then right click on "ArcGIS for Desktop" -> Select "Uninstall/change".

The ArcGIS Setup dialog will pop up. Chose the "Repair" option.

After finishing the Repair procedures the ArcGIS will be working properly!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by repairing the data interop. installation.  I also have background processing turned off.