# Turning on metadata geoprocessing history for feature class after export/copy from in_memory workspace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, in-memory

I usually run a series of geoprocessing tools by using in_memory workspace before saving a clean version of my feature classes. Most of the time geoprocessing history related to this final copy has no importance. However the project that I am currently working on requires me to keep geoprocessing history but somehow in_memory does not keep this information.

The snapshot of the metadata section is as follows:
[image]

I have found this ArcGIS Idea to [Allow IN_MEMORY datasets to store metadata generated by geo-processing tools](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/8880), which talks about exactly the same problem, but was wondering if anyone has got any workaround to this problem?

Comment: No! :) Hopefully your question here with drive people to visit that idea and vote it up so that ESRI will start paying attention?

Comment: @Hornbydd, I agree, there should be a trigger to let in_memory to collect this information in expense of higher memory usage. In fact it can be a relatively small file accompanying in_memory items with a certain size. I asked this here to first see if anyone has come up with an idea to overcome this issue (I was thinking an elegant way of picking up geoprocessing history items from ArcGIS Toolbox logs and save them into the feature classes xml), second to have this question in stack exchange for experts attention, and finally, as you said, advertise the idea ;)

Comment: @Hornbydd, I do not want this question to open unanswered for a long time knowing that your **submitted idea** is as closest to the possible answer...

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138789/improving-arcgis-results-saving-and-manipulating

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned at the end of your question that you:

> have found this ArcGIS Idea to [Allow IN_MEMORY datasets to store
>   metadata generated by geo-processing tools](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/8880), which talks about
>   exactly the same problem

I think voting on that is as much as we can currently do to try and meet your requirement.

Comment: Could not agree more!